# How can I convert a date in an rdlc

Tags: date, reporting-services, rdlc

I get an error in an rdlc file. This works if `Parameters!testDate.Value` is not blank, but fails if it is blank. If I leave the CDate part off, then placeholder property date formatter does not work properly, but putting the CDate displays an #Error on the report `Parameters!testDate.Value` is blank.

```
=IIf(Len(Parameters!testDate.Value)=0,Nothing,CDate(Parameters!testDate.Value))
```

This also does not work

```
=IIf(FormatDateTime(Parameters!testDate.Value,2)=CDate("1/1/0001"),"",CDate(FormatDateTime(Parameters!testDate.Value,2)))
```

This does not work either

```
=IIf(FormatDateTime(Parameters!testDate.Value,2)=CDate("1/1/0001") or Len(Parameters!testDate.Value)=0 or IsNothing(Parameters!testDate.Value),"",FormatDateTime(Parameters!testDatete.Value,2))
```

Comment: What type is "testDate" ? Is it a  `DateTime`, `string` or something else?

Comment: Yes testDate is a string

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the value is NULL. You can use the following expression.

```
=iif(IsNothing(Parameters!testDate.Value), "value is NULL", CDate(Parameters!testDate.Value))
```